# Why is inf getting printed when i execute this code?

Tags: python, c, recursion

```
def recur(a): 
  if( (a/2)!=0): 
    return recur(a/2) * 10+a%2
  else: 
      return 1
c=recur(10)
print(c)
```

inf is getting printed when i am executing this code.can any one explain my faults and this code.
(i converted this code from C to python; the original code is given below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int recur(int n)
{
    if((n/2)!=0)
     return (recur(n/2)*10+n%2);
    
    else
      return 1;
}
int main()
{ int d;
d=recur(10);
    printf("%d",d);

    return 0;
}
```

**output**
1010

Comment: Integers can't have "infinite" values, only floating point types. But signed integer arithmetic overflow leads to *undefined behavior*, which could be an issue in the C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering a question in the comments, here's how you get `1010` as the result.
Let's trace the execution of recur:

```
recur( 10 )
  return recur( 5 ) * 10 + 10 % 2 ---------+
    return recur( 2 ) * 10 + 5 % 2 ------+ |
      return recur( 1 ) * 10 + 2 % 2 --+ | |
        return 1                       | | |
      1 * 10 + 2 % 2 == 10 + 0 == 10 <-+ | |
    10 * 10 + 5 % 2 == 100 + 1 == 101 <--+ |
  101 * 10 + 10 % 2 == 1010 + 0 == 1010 <--+
```

IOW, to compute the result of `recur(10)`, we compute the result of `recur(10/2)`, or `recur(5)`, multiply that by `10`, and add the result of `10 % 2` (`0`).

To compute the result of `recur(5)`, we compute the result of `recur(5/2)`, or `recur(2)`, multiply that by `10`, and add the result of `5 % 2` (`1`).

To compute the result of `recur(2)`, we compute the result of `recur(2/2)`, or `recur(1)`, multiply that by `10`, and add the result of `2 % 2` (`0`).

`1/2 == 0`, so the result of `recur(1)` is `1`.  `1 * 10 + 2 % 2` is `10`, so the result of `recur(2)` is `10`.  `10 * 10 + 5 % 2` is `101`, so the result of `recur(5)` is `101`.  And finally, the result of `101 * 10 + 10 % 2` is `1010`, so that's the result of `recur(10)`.

In C, integer division yields an integer result, so `1/2 == 0`, `5/2 == 2`, etc.

Comment: I appreciate it.Is this recur() calculating binary equivalent of a no.? Coz if we enter 0 it shall return 1

Comment: @TDe: It’s a decimal number, but yeah, it’s computing the sequence of binary digits for a given input value.  This particular algorithm will only work for positive values.  You won’t get the expected result for 0 or negative values.

Answer (score 8):

The division operator `/` in Python 3 is a floating point division, so your loop will run forever. replace by `//` and be happy.

Comment: I'd also recommend getting into the habit of using inequalities for testing:  `if((a // 2) > 0):...`

Comment: but,can you explain me why the output is 1010 and not 1100

Comment: Because your code is converting the value to binary representation and the binary representation of 10 is 1010 because `10 = 8*1 + 4*0 + 2*1 + 1*0`